# Is it possible to select any wifi connection before login into windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

The situation:
Im am working as helpdesk support and sometimes i have to reset passwords for bussiness network accounts. Users work from their home using vpn and need passwords to be resseted. The problem is when the user is not connected to wifi before login into windows. In this case, the machine do not recognize the new password and cant sync with the server, we have to ask them to go to the office and connect by cable to perform sync of the new pass. For some reason, some users, do not connect automatically to the last wifi connection established in windows.

The question: Is there any way to select a wifi connection before login into windows? so to avoid asking users to move from their home?

Answer (score 0):

If the said user can't connect the laptop to a VPN network (Not a published apps citrix environment) syncing to a DC, it won't change anything to have Windows to connect to Wifi before it loads. What I mean by that is, if the user can't login, obviously, he/she can't connect to the office using the VPN client.

So the best solution for this case is having the user to use his/her old password to login and then, from Webmail to change the password. Unless the helpdesk member sets a new password (To change at next logon to be ISO 27001 compliant).

There is a not a lot of solutions for you there but nonetheless, here's a link to set GPO and local setup to have the PC to connect to the first available WiFi.

[community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2047-enable-wireless-connection-pre-logon-on-domain](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2047-enable-wireless-connection-pre-logon-on-domain)